# Git checkout - switching back to HEAD

Tags: git, git-checkout

I've been doing my project while at some point I discovered that one thing stopped working. I needed to look up the state of my code when it was working correctly, so I've decided to use git checkout (because I wanted to check-something-out). And so I've done

```
git checkout SHA
```

couple times while going back to point from which I can't go to HEAD, the output is following:

```
git checkout SHA-HEAD

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    [list of files]
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I am pretty much sure I have NOT changed anything. The command

```
git checkout master
```

gives the same output.

Is there a way to go back to HEAD?

What is the safe way of "jumping over" history commits?

Comment: If you don't want to keep those changes `git clean -f` will clean all the untracked files. Then checkout to master

Comment: The `error: ...` message means that you—or something you did, perhaps indirectly— *did* change the files. You can tell Git to discard or overwrite these changes, or use `git status` and/or `git diff` to see what, precisely, changed. It could be as simple as some kind of line-ending modification, or some command that runs in the background that wrote to a file. (Aside: "go back to HEAD" makes no sense in Git, as you're *always* on HEAD: `HEAD` literally means "current commit". You can *change* HEAD, after which you're still on HEAD, just a different HEAD. This is ... difficult to phrase. :-) )

Comment: Git is loaded with mechanisms, so here are two: `git reset --hard HEAD` means "reset the index and work-tree to match HEAD", i.e., throw away changes. Or: `git checkout -f master` means "change HEAD to be `master`, even if that means throwing away some work": `-f` means "force".

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can `stash` (save the changes in temporary place) then, back to `master` branch HEAD.

```
$ git add .
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
```

Note that some sites have changed the name of the default branch from "master" to "main" so you might have to use `git checkout main` instead.

---

**Jump Over Commits Back and Forth:**

- Go to a specific `commit-sha`.

  ```
    $ git checkout <commit-sha>
  ```
- If you have uncommitted changes here then, you can checkout to a new branch | Add | Commit | Push the current branch to the remote.

  ```
    # checkout a new branch, add, commit, push
    $ git checkout -b <branch-name>
    $ git add .
    $ git commit -m 'Commit message'
    $ git push origin HEAD          # push the current branch to remote 

    $ git checkout master           # back to master branch now
  ```
- If you have changes in the specific commit and don't want to keep the changes, you can do `stash` or `reset` then checkout to `master` (or, any other branch).

  ```
    # stash
    $ git add -A
    $ git stash
    $ git checkout master

    # reset
    $ git reset --hard HEAD
    $ git checkout master
  ```
- After checking out a specific commit if you have no uncommitted change(s) then, just back to `master` or `other` branch.

  ```
    $ git status          # see the changes
    $ git checkout master

    # or, shortcut
    $ git checkout -      # back to the previous state
  ```

Comment: That solved my problem - partially.
Still I need to know how to jump over commits back and forth without consequences.

Comment: @rbraun, I have edited my answer showing how you can jump over commits back and forth.

Comment: Whew. I was wondering why I can see the changes I made in a branch in the master. It was due to I have not `add`, `commit`, and `push` the branch to `origin`. Your solution worked.

Comment: A time saver, why Git don't create itself as more human-like things, I see there is tons of questions about it, and it is just a version control software=.=!

Comment: with git 2.17.1, `git checkout master` => "_error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git_" but `git checkout -` is fine.

Comment: In case you run into this, this happens because the branch might not be named `master` (recent github policy changes ;-) ), so try `git branch` to check the branch name, then `git checkout <mybranchname>`

Comment: Why you use  $ git add -A before $ git stash

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN -A (or. --all) is used to add file contents to the index (it will find new files, staged modified files or, removed files)

Comment: git stash adds working directory also why do we have to stage them?

Comment: ```git checkout main``` worked for me

Answer (score 7):

## Short Answer

```
git reset --hard
git checkout HEAD
```

This removes any changes and gets you back to the branch HEAD where you came from.